# Why java collection classes are declared to have redundant interfaces?

Tags: java, collections

```
public class HashMap<K,V>
extends AbstractMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable
```

Here the part implements Map is unnecessary as AbstractMap already implements Map.Why all similar collection classes declaration have this redundancy?